# How to write a test that checks if was added type annotation in function?

Tags: python

I have a function.

```py
def func(num: int, item: str) -> list:
   pass
```

And I want to add a test that checks that function and parameters have a type annotation. It is needed by other developers don't change input and output types.

Any idea how to do that? I want to use pytest, maybe mocks?

Comment: What would you mock? You can see what annotations were provided by checking `__annotations__`, but that would be quite brittle - what if someone changed it to return a `Sequence` instead of a `list`, should that really fail the test? Maybe you want a type checker like MyPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) function from typing:

```
import typing
from typing import Callable


def func(num: int, item: str) -> list:
    pass


def func_bad(num, item):
    pass


def test_has_annotation(f: Callable) -> bool:
    hints = typing.get_type_hints(f)
    print(hints)  # to check what this returns
    return bool(hints)


print(test_has_annotation(func))
print(test_has_annotation(func_bad))
```

Result:

```
{'num': <class 'int'>, 'item': <class 'str'>, 'return': <class 'list'>}
True
{}
False
```

Comment: Surely just `return bool(hints)`?